# PHP MySQL object stmt without result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

trying to update to avoid SQL injection from this

```
$codigo=$_POST['voucher'];
$resultado = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM vale WHERE codigo=\''.$codigo.'\'');
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado);
```

to this...

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$username,$passdb,$db_name);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT usuario,creditos FROM vale WHERE codigo=?');
$stmt->bind_param("s", $codigo);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($usuariocodigo,$creditoscodigo);
```

First works but vulnerable and mysql_query is depracated. Second wont give any result. Tried everything. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Do you run a `fetch`? The `bind_result` only associates the columns to variables. The `fetch` still needs to be called to iterate over result set. e.g. `while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf("%s %s\n", $usuariocodigo,$creditoscodigo);
    }`

Comment: How are you ascertaining that the second (correct) version won't yield any results?

Comment: Please be advised, just a single line `new mysqli` is not enough. There is a lot of things need to be done on [mysqli connect](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect)

Comment: while ($stmt->fetch())  {code} worked fine couldnt make any of other answers work. Thanks @user3783243

Answer (score 1):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$username,$passdb,$db_name);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT usuario,creditos FROM vale WHERE codigo=?');
$stmt->bind_param("s", $codigo);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
```

$rows will contain the data as an array

Comment: I bet you should have kept a single row fetch, to match mysql_fetch_assoc fro the obsoleted version

Comment: @Your Common Sense Sorry I don't understand what you mean

Comment: undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result(),  i probably have something else missing

Comment: @will what PHP version you are using? What operation system?